# When to use ports in your UML component diagram?

Tags: components, uml, component-diagram

I'm trying to understand some UML diagrams, and I was reading and drawing some different diagrams, until I reached the component diagram.

I was following some online tutorials, [like this](https://www.visual-paradigm.com/guide/uml-unified-modeling-language/what-is-component-diagram/) and [this](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/port.html?context=components).

Just like the question's title says, I don't understand when to use a port in a component, both websites above seems to be answering how to use port and providing some general definitions like:

> A port is often used to help expose required and provided interfaces of a component.

However no one is giving a good answer for when to use it.

What makes me ask this question is that, many examples I stumbled upon sometimes uses ports in their components and some times not.

Are there characteristics or rules that may help define whether to use a port or not ?

I'm pretty new to UML and design in general so please don't judge my ignorance in this area.